# Delete from 2 SQL tables with SilverLight Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq-to-sql

I got 2 tables in SQL that both have a field called Selection_ID. I want to delete all rows with `Selection_ID = inpSelectionID` using the Linq-to-SQL.

**My tables:**
[image]

**My C# function:**

```
void buttonDeleteSelectionList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, Canvas canvasAdvancedSearchFieldResults, int inpSelectionID)
{

    PositionServiceReference.PositionServiceClient service = new PositionServiceReference.PositionServiceClient();
    service.DeleteSelectionCompleted += new EventHandler<System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(service_DeleteSelectionCompleted);
    service.DeleteSelectionAsync(inpSelectionID);
}
```

**My Service Code PositionService.svc.cs:**

```
[OperationContract]
void DeleteSelection(int inpSelectionID)
{
    PositionDataClassesDataContext context = new PositionDataClassesDataContext();

    context.Lloyds_Selection.DeleteOnSubmit(inpSelectionID);
    context.SubmitChanges();

    context.Lloyds_Selection_Vessels.DeleteOnSubmit(inpSelectionID);
    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DeleteOnSubmit` requires the entity object as a parameter, so you can't delete item without selecting it from database first. There is `DeleteAllOnSubmit` method too, but it requires `IEnumerable` of entities as well. You can use it like that:

```
context.Lloyds_Selection.DeleteAllOnSubmit(context.Lloyds_Selection.Where(l => l.Selection_ID  == inpSelectionID));
```

However, you can use `DataContext.ExecuteCommand` to execute raw SQL against your database:

```
string command = string.format("DELETE FROM Lloyds_Section WHERE Selection_ID = {0}", inpSelectionID");
context.ExecuteCommand(command );
```